# webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin add font

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Hello I'm new using webpack and i'm having a problem adding a font

in the `webpack.config.js` I have the html template like this:

```
plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: '/var/lib/cornerstone3D/utils/PROYECTO/template.html',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
         __BASE_PATH__: "''",
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            {
                from: '../../../node_modules/@cornerstonejs/dicom-image-loader/dist/dynamic-import',
                to: '/var/lib/cornerstone3D/utils/PROYECTO/dist',
            },
        ],
    }),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
],

entry: path.join('/var/lib/cornerstone3D/packages/tools/proyecto', './editor/index.ts'),
output: {
    path: '/var/lib/cornerstone3D/utils/PROYECTO/dist',
    filename: 'editor.js',
},
```

then in the rules I have the file loader for the font files.

```
{
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: ''
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

I import the fonts in the javascript and then in the html

```
<link type="css" rel="stylesheet" 
 href="./packages/tools/proyecto/editor/fonts/Montserrat/stylesheet.css">
```

I also tried

```
<link type="css" rel="stylesheet" href="./fonts/Montserrat/stylesheet.css">
```

but it cannot find the `stylesheet.css`. I put the fonts in the root folder of the project, in the folder of the typescript and also in the folder of the html template, but it won't change the font.

In the `stylesheet.css` I have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratbold';

    src: url('montserrat-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('montserrat-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('montserrat-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('montserrat-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('montserrat-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('montserrat-bold-webfont.svg#montserratbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Could anybody help me please?

Comment: Did you read the [loading fonts](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts) guide?